# js only for a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my page I have many buttons, but I would like that a scripts runs only for one of them.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        if (window.localStorage.getItem('accept_cookies')) {
          $("button").parent().parent().closest('div').hide(); 

        }
      $("button").click(function() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('accept_cookies', true);
        $(this).parent().parent().closest('div').hide();

      });

      });
 </script>
```

The button is:

```
<button id="i" class="oneclass">OK</button>
```

but if I try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('accept_cookies')) {
      $document.getElementById("i").parent().parent().closest('div').hide(); 

    }
  $(document).getElementById("i").click(function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('accept_cookies', true);
    $(this).parent().parent().closest('div').hide();

  });

  });
```

it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: FTFY rather than using `.parent()` and restricting any future DOM element restructuring, use an identifier.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: In cases like this, it might be wise to look at the developer console. It should give you some info about what exactly causes your script to fail. The next step would be to research the error and look for similar cases. Learning this will help you solve most  issues, like this one, by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks, im still learning js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your jquery selector like that:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        if (window.localStorage.getItem('accept_cookies')) {
          $("#i").parent().parent().closest('div').hide(); 

        }
      $("#i").click(function() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('accept_cookies', true);
        $(this).parent().parent().closest('div').hide();

      });

      });
 </script>
```

Instead of selecting all buttons, select just yours by it id: `#i`